# I can't use Try-except

Tags: python, debugging, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

I have a page that I want to scrape but it's not always available to be scraped
and I want the code to be running 24/7
So I made this

```
import requests
import response
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import io
import ssl
import os
import getpass
import urllib3
from time import sleep
from lxml.etree import tostring
import subprocess
import smtplib
import sys
import lxml
print('Enter the National-ID : ')
NID = input()
burp0_url = "I removed the URL"
burp0_cookies = {"I removed the cookies"}
burp0_headers = {"I removed the headers"}
burp0_data = "I removed the data"
r = requests.post(burp0_url, headers=burp0_headers, cookies=burp0_cookies, data=burp0_data)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
script = soup.find('script')
address = soup.find("input", {"name": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpAdrs"})
DOB = soup.find("input", {"name": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpBD"})
gender = soup.find('option', {'selected':'selected'})
status = soup.find('option', {'value':'206510000'})
for x in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'auto-style1'}):
    for no in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpNatNo'}):
        for name in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName'}):
            with io.open('x.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                ary = [name , no, address, DOB]      
                f.write (ary[0]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[1]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[2]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[3]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (gender.text + ",")
                f.write (status.text + "\n")
                print (script)
```

My issue is when the program doesn't find (value) or whatever it ends the program
like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Crybik\Desktop\jms\CORVID\Coding\py\1oen.py", line 35, in <module>
    f.write (ary[0]["value"]+ ",")
  File "C:\python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'value'
```

I want it to keep executing it
I tried to do the try-except thing But I couldn't and it didn't work
And I think Try-except doesn't show Bugs when I have to debug them.
So can someone please help me?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question. Explain "didn't work". For exception printing there is module "traceback" with function "print_exc" to print a caught exception in an "except" block

Comment: What does print_exc do?

Comment: Prints the traceback of the currently handled exception (as the usual tracebacks) but you can continue execution after the print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print your fields in a loop so you can put `try/except` around each of them.

Use this:

```
for x in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'auto-style1'}):
    for no in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpNatNo'}):
        for name in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName'}):
            with io.open('x.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                ary = [name , no, address, DOB]
                for field in ary:
                    try:
                        val = field["value"]
                    except:
                        val = ""
                    f.write(val + ",")
                f.write (gender.text + ",")
                f.write (status.text + "\n")
                print(script)
```

in place of this:

```
for x in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'auto-style1'}):
    for no in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpNatNo'}):
        for name in soup.findAll('input', {'name':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmpName'}):
            with io.open('x.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                ary = [name , no, address, DOB]      
                f.write (ary[0]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[1]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[2]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (ary[3]["value"]+ ",")
                f.write (gender.text + ",")
                f.write (status.text + "\n")
                print (script)
```

Comment: I got this error
`
    except:
           ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
`

Comment: You must not have indented your code correctly when copying. Make sure you're consistent in using spaces or tabs.

Comment: the code
[link](https://c.top4top.io/p_20091q7eh1.png)

Comment: I included the ary above the 
But can you tell me what's wrong with the code ? I tried to keep tapping it nothing changes

Comment: Your `except:` line isn't at the same indentation as `try`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how my change fits into your loops. I thought it would be obvious, but I guess not.

Comment: f.write (ary[0]["value"]+ ",")
  File "C:\python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'value'

Comment: That's not in my answer.

Comment: the code [link](https://l.top4top.io/p_2009cwg511.png)

Comment: The `for field in ary:` loop is a replacement for each of the lines with `ary[0]`, `ary[1]`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, bear with me please I typed
for field in ary[0]:
But I'm still getting the error 
 f.write (ary[0]["value"]+ ",")

Comment: You shouldn't have `ary[0]` anywhere.

Comment: I copied it but it's still giving the same error [link](https://c.top4top.io/p_2009n5kjr1.png)

Comment: You still have `ary[0]["value"]` in your code. I don't know why you can't copy my code properly.

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot. you are a life saviour